# Set image for tab bar IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm experiencing issue when trying to set png image for tab bar item icon for my iOS application. If I'm creating png image (with transparent background) and setting it, everything works as expected, but when I'm using another png file (created by another person, or downloaded from web) it not works. Actually in my case I'm making png file from .pdf file and it's absolutely not clear for me why this not works. For more information please see screen captures below (top image represents not working one).

[image] [image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those specific icons/buttons work funky in terms of PNG and transparency for those images. You have to have look at the png's you download in image preview, make sure transparency exists for the white space.  If there is whitespace it'll come through and show in your iOS app. Any other nonwhitepsace transparency will show up dark. It threw me off the first time I encountered this, A lot of graphics and PNG's you download from the internet doesn't have transparency built in or they have it very subtle. THose will show up as a blob for your ViewController Tabs.

Here is a good resource and guideline I found: http://steveweller.com/articles/toolbar-icons/

Comment: Thanks for hint Amit. Just want to add some details, as far as I was able to understand after many experiments my icons (both 60X60 and 30X30) should not fully fill image, they should cover some area in the image and the rest should be transparent. I found this after investigating many tabbed applications installed in my phone. All have some strong background and small icons inside.